# Adding a PodDisruptionBudget to fluentd-gcp pods in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My `fluentd-gcp` pods are like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: 2019-08-06T23:41:17Z
  generateName: fluentd-gcp-v3.1.1-
  labels:
    controller-revision-hash: 7cbbc7496
    k8s-app: fluentd-gcp
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    pod-template-generation: "4"
    version: v3.1.1
  name: fluentd-gcp-v3.1.1-jpd5x
  namespace: kube-system
```

I tried to add a Pod Disruption Budget like this

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: fluentd-gcp
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd-gcp
```

However, the `allowed disruptions` value is 0

```
$ kubectl get pdb
NAME               MIN AVAILABLE   MAX UNAVAILABLE   ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS   AGE
fluentd-gcp        1               N/A               0                     9s
```

which indicates that there is no matching pod with that label as mentioned here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#check-the-status-of-the-pdb

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS` describes pods that are candidates for eviction rather than the number of pods
the `PDB` has seen.

If you do `$ kubectl describe pdb NAME`, you'll see the `current` field, which describes accurately how many pods are being matched by the `PDB` using the mentioned labels.

Although is not specified in your question, consider that by default in GKE `fluentd-gcp` is run as a `DaemonSet`, this means that the [number of replicas depends on the number of nodes in the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

This would prevent the `PDB` to mark these pods as evictable, as they depend on the nodes rather than the number in the `ReplicaSet`.